# SQLite get number of tables from a database

Tags: c#, sqlite, count

How can I get the total number of tables from a database?
My code is below:

```
string sDatabasePath = DBPath();
SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder datasource = new SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder();
datasource.Add("Data Source", sDatabasePath);
datasource.Add("Version", "3");
datasource.Add("New", "False");
datasource.Add("Compress", "True");             
//int nTables;
using (SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(datasource.ConnectionString))
{
    connection.Open(); //opens connection
    SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand("Select Count(*) FROM sqlite_master where type='table' as nTables;");
    //SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sqlite_master where type='table'", connection);
    Int32 nTables = (Int32) comm .ExecuteScalar(); //this query raises error Specified cast is not valid.
    connection.Close(); // closes the connection
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ExecuteScalar() method returns a single value. This would be used to return the result of a calculation. Such as requesting a COUNT.

```
cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

The returned value is an Object of the result.

What you can do is try in following way to convert to Int32

```
object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
int nTables = Convert.ToInt32(result);
```

Comment: Thanks Jigar, your code worked. Also, I don't need to declare the object result (although it is more clear for me this way). It alse works to say directly int nTables = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL syntax has some problems:

```
Select Count(*) FROM sqlite_master where type='table' as nTables);
```

should be e.g.

```
Select Count(*) as nTables FROM sqlite_master where type='table';
```

The `as nTables` was misplaced, there was an extra `)`, and `"` was not terminated. The last one was probably just an issue posting the question since that would also be invalid C# syntax.

Also, when asking about problems with your code, it always helps to include the specific errors in the question itself.

Comment: Hi Laalto. I added the error description soon after posting. I tried the code you sent me and it still gives error: System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

Comment: If I change the next line to comm.ExecuteScalar(); instead of nTables = (Int32) comm.ExecuteScalar(), there are no errors, but the number of tables is zero instead of 4.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';
```

Comment: Thanks. It gives error: System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: SQL logic error or missing database
no such table: sqlite_master.tables

Comment: Hi Farzi. The "connection" contains all the database details (name and path) and I can run other queries fine. I tried replacing the dbname with my database name, with or without extension and it still does not work - I get error System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: SQL logic error or missing database
no such table: sDatabasePath.sqlite_master

Comment: This query is returning the correct result when I run it in my SqliteDb..I think the pbm is in your C# code because query is correct

Comment: The query as you wrote last time executes without errors for me too. The problem I had was obtaining the count value. For whatever reason, the next line Int32 nTables = (Int32) comm .ExecuteScalar(); did not run as expected and Jigar provided the solution. Thanks for help anyway.